# How do I pass model information to this each statement in a nested template?

Tags: ember.js

I have an index route where I need to populate a menu in one outlet based on a list of models. However I cannot get the models to be represented in the each statement.

Here is the **Category Model**:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    parent: DS.belongsTo('App.Category')
})
```

And here is the **indexRoute** where I render it

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render('index')
    this.render('categoryMenu',
        {
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            into: 'index',
            model: function() {
                return App.Category.find()
            },
            controller: App.CategoriesController
        })
    this.render('badgesList',{
        outlet: 'badgesList',
        into: 'index'
    })
}
})
```

**Index Template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="span3">
        {{outlet sidebar}}
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
       {{outlet badgesList}}
    </div>
</script>
```

**Nested Category Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="categoryMenu">
    <ul>
        {{#each model}}
            {{title}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

I have tried to change the each statement to several different things like *controller* or *item in model* but nothing is displayed.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I was misled by your original code snippet. Where you place the `model` property in the `render` options hash, I got really excited that this would solve a problem I was having. But it turns out, that option does nothing and you need to use the [`controllerFor`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1820) route helper to set up the controller's model before calling render. Excellent question, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make yourself `CategoriesController` first like this:

```
App.CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: function () {
        return App.Category.find()
    }.property()
});
```

rename your template just to `categories`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="categories">
    <ul>
        {{#each model}}
                {{title}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

in your `index` template replace `{{outlet}}` with `{{render 'categoies'}}`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div class="span3">
        {{render 'categoies'}}
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
           {{outlet badgesList}}
    </div>
</script>
```

as last thing remove the call rendering `categoryMenu`.